# Benchmarking for multiple parallel reuquests with php

Tags: php, curl, benchmarking, php-5.3

What is the best practice for benchmarking in PHP?

This is what I want to do:

I have setup a Saas product and I want to issue with cURL multiple parallel http requests towards that URL.

Up to now I have built a cURL function that looks like so:

```
function getCurl($strUrl, $arrParams, $intTimeout = null, $blnReturn = true, $blnVerbose = false, $blnHeader = false){
    if(isset($strUrl)){
        if(is_array($arrParams)){   
            $strUrl.= '?';
            foreach($arrParams as $key=>$value){
                $strUrl.=$key.'='.$value;
                $strUrl.='&';
            }
            $strUrl = substr_replace($strUrl,'',strlen($strUrl)-1,1);           
            try{
                $curl = curl_init($strUrl);
            }catch(Exception $e){
                throw new Exception('Invalid URL');
            }           
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, $blnReturn);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, $blnVerbose);
            if($intTimeout){
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $intTimeout);
            }
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $blnHeader);
            if(strpos($strUrl, 'https') !== FALSE){
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
            }
            $data = curl_exec($curl);       
            if($blnReturn){
                return $data;
            }
            curl_close($curl);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Any idea how to improve this to allow parallel reuests? 
Any other way to do this in respect to best practice?

Thank you!

Comment: Never used it, how efficient is it?

Comment: curl_multi is a php function to download stacks of URLs. It is wrapped in this class: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsemlabs.co.uk%2Fjournal%2Fobject-oriented-curl-class-with-multi-threading&ei=AKGfUubVEOf-ygPiv4GICw&usg=AFQjCNGO_09luiZ2J6B7tR2mHWjXNqIgag&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGQ

But it does not download in parallel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CURL does not do parallel requests.

You will need to install puf (apt-get install puf    in UB) if you want parallel HTTP requests:

```
puf -lc 20 -Tc 20 -Td 20 -i list-of-urls.txt
```

Download a \n separated list of urls from a file w/ 20 parallel connections.

You could also look at pthreads in PHP, this may do parallel requests; not sure.